Error en paginación

Estoy realizando un proyecto, lleva una paginación pero el problema es que apenas estoy empezando a entender PHP y me estoy guiando de videos pero me esta causando un error.
Mi proyecto es de un sistema de un catalogo de refacciones, se divide en marcas-submarcas-refacciones, en la refacciones estoy usando la paginación, pero cuando intento ir a las siguiente pagina con el resto de refacciones me esta llevando a las refacciones de otra submarca.
<div class="button-container">
    <?php
    $anterior = $data['pagina'] - 1;
    $siguiente = $data['pagina'] + 1; 
    $id_version = isset($_GET['id_version']) ? $_GET['id_version'] : '';

    if ($data['pagina'] > 1) {
        echo '<button class="nav-button prev-button">
            <a href="?page=' . $anterior . '&id_version=' . $id_version . '">Anterior</a>
            </button>';
    }
    if ($data['pagina'] < $data['total']) {
        echo '<button class="nav-button next-button">
            <a href="?page=' . $siguiente . '&id_version=' . $id_version . '">Siguiente</a>
            </button>';
      }
    ?>
</div>

y este es la parte del controlador principal
// Vista de refacciones con paginación
    public function refaccion($id_version)
    {
        $pagina = (empty($page)) ? 1 : $page;
        $porPagina = 20;
        $desde = ($pagina - 1) * $porPagina;
        $data['title'] = 'Refacciones';
        $data['refaccion'] = $this->model->getrefacciones($id_version, $desde, $porPagina);
        $data['pagina'] = $pagina;
        $total = $this->model->getTotalRefacciones();
        $data['total'] = ceil($total['total'] / $porPagina);

        $this->views->getView('principal', "refaccion", $data);
    }

Model.php
// Obtener refacción por ID  
    public function getrefaccion($id_refaccion)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT p.*, c.submarca, m.marca 
            FROM refaccion p 
            INNER JOIN submarca c ON p.id_version = c.id_version 
            INNER JOIN marca m ON c.id_marca = m.id_marca 
            WHERE p.id_refaccion = $id_refaccion";
        return $this->select($sql); 
    }

    // Obtener todas las refacciones con paginación
    public function getrefacciones($id_version, $desde, $porPagina)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM refaccion WHERE id_version = $id_version LIMIT $desde, $porPagina";
        return $this->selectAll($sql);
    }

    // Obtener total de refacciones
    public function getTotalRefacciones()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM refaccion";
        return $this->select($sql);
    }

Podrían ayudarme por favor.

No vemos la consulta getrefacciones() del model ese, y no sabemos la estructura de tu base de datos ni las tablas implicadas, pero pinta que es allí donde debes mirar, pues si te basas en el id_version para sacar el resto de datos, me da que no estas comprobando bien la "submarca" a la que pertecene para filtrar esa consulta (y todo esto a ciegas, así que es probable que me equivoque).  Léete [example] para mejorar tu pregunta, gracias.

Cierto olvidaba agregar, gracias. Insertare el model en el post, espero pueda revisarlo... gracias

esa query para obtener refacciones esta bien? que es el id_version.. dejanos ver tu tabla...

Primero no entiendo, dentro de la función refaccion($pagina) de donde consigues que la variable  $page te pueda hacer caso, pues no la veo ni pasada en la función ni tampoco en la clase (sería más bien $this->page si es que la defines en el constructor o algo).  Luego te recomiendo repasar la consulta de getreacciones y usarla en un phpmyadmin o en otra parte,para comprobar sus resultados,pues no acabo de entender si un $id_version puede pertener o no a varias marcas y submarcas, o es único para una sola de ellas en cada ocasión. Si dices que ves otras submarcas será porque no lo es.

Y luego, el getTotalRefacciones() no lo haces en función del $id_version, por lo tanto siempre te mostrará la cantidad total de registros, sean o no de ese $id_version.  Diria que el problema es más de base que de otra cosa. Acláranos que representa que es eso del $id_version y su relación con las marcas y submarcas.

si, edite el post...

Bueno, está claro que te falla algo en tu estructura de la base de datos para empezar, pero no sabria decirte el qué, pues por un lado repites el id_marca en las tablas refaccion y submarca, cuando la key de la tabla submarca es id_version.  Empieza aclarando eso y luego seguimos, pues o bien es innecesario el campo id_marca en la tabla refaccion o bien la key de la tabla submarca debe ser compuesta de dos elementos, id_version + id_marca.  Luego, viendo eso, las consultas de las funciones getrefacciones() y getTotalRefacciones() no tienen sentido tal como pretendes usarlas.
